# Linebreaks in socket server?

Tags: python, sockets, line-breaks

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the linebreaks in this? Every time a string is echoed there is a linebreak on it. Basically an empty character. How can I get rid of that?

```
from socket import *
import threading
import thread

def handler(clientsock,addr):
    while 1:
        data = clientsock.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not data:
            break
        msg = data
        print msg
        clientsock.send(msg)
    clientsock.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 20000
    BUFSIZ = 1024
    ADDR = (host, port)
    serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serversock.bind(ADDR)
    serversock.listen(2)

print 'Version 0.1','-',host,':',port

while 1:
    clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
    print 'initiated',addr[0],'on',addr[1]
    thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsock, addr))
```

Comment: don't use wild card import (`*`) unless in a REPL.

Comment: use `.sendall()` otherwise not all data might be send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
print msg
```

with

```
sys.stdout.write(msg)
```

obviously with `import sys` on the top. The reason the newline appears is because for ease of usage `print` adds it to every print automatically. `sys.stdout.write` doesn't do this.

Comment: Make perfect sense. Thank you.. Is there a way I can reassign `msg` without the linebreak?

Comment: Another option is to add a comma after the print statement: `print msg,`

Comment: @Matthew, `msg` doesn't have the linebreak, in fact. It is appended by the `print` statement.

Comment: You could flush `stdout` on a newline if it is not redirected to a file, pipe i.e., if it is not interactive: `if getattr(sys.stdout, 'isatty', lambda: False)() and any(n in msg for n in b'\r\n'): sys.stdout.flush()`

Answer (score 0):

@nightcracker has already answered the question, I just want to leave here another possible solution. One can add a comma after a `print` statement to suppress adding a newline after the string.

```
print msg, # <- notice the comma
```

From the [Language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print):

> A `'\n'` character is written at the end, unless the `print` statement ends with a comma. This is the only action if the statement contains just the keyword `print`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian only between calls to `print`, AFAIK

Comment: `print` may be called more than once. If a previous call haven't ended with a newline (softspace is true) then it prints `" "` but the OP wants to get rid of "empty" characters. `print s,` translates to [`PRINT_ITEM` opcode](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Python/ceval.c#l1751).